# Firefox is currently in offline mode and can't browse the Web - Offline App Test

Tags: firefox, offline-caching, offline-browsing

For testing purpose I tried to switch to offline mode (*File* > *Work offline*), and upon refresh, it showed "**Firefox is currently in offline mode and can't browse the Web.**"

When I clicked "**Try Again**" it went back "**Online**" again.

How can I work offline to see how my app performing offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your settings for Firefox.

In Ubuntu, go to

*Edit* > *Preferences* > *Advanced* > *Network*

Under **Offline Web Content and User Data**, see how much space is used by Firefox.

If it shows

> "**Your application cache is currently 0 bytes of disk space**",
>
> **0 bytes**

it probably means you disabled the Firefox offline cache.

Type "**about:config**" into the address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then click the "**I'll be careful, I promise!**" button and search for these values:

`browser.cache.disk.enable    user set boolean false
browser.cache.memory.enable  user set boolean false`

Please refer to Mozilla Firefox support before you do something there.

[Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1020103)

If you are using Firebug, that you may have enabled the *Disable Browser Cache* option within the [*Net* Panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel). Disable that option and try again.

Another issue you may get with **FireQuery**,
If you see something like

> TypeError: this.__FireQueryShared is undefined

remove **FireQuery** add-on and try again.